# how to remove dot (list view) from h:message

Tags: java, html, css, error-handling, jsf-1.2

I am using `<h:messages globalOnly="true"/>` to display error messages.

When error comes, it shows in below format.

[image]

Any idea how can I remove this dot and spaces and just show the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the messages render as table cells instead of list items:

```
<h:messages globalOnly="true" layout="table"/>
```

Documentation for `h:messages` is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/messages.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could download firebug plugin for firefox and trace the css    , maybe try     this css:

```
.item-list ul li
{
list-style-type: none;
list-style-image: none;
}
```